# Collection of sets inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A = \bigl\{ \{a,b\}, \{b,c\} \bigr\}$
> and $B = \bigl\{ \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b,c\} \bigr\}$.
>
> Is $\{b\} \in A$? Also, is $b \in A$? And, is $\{b\} \in A \cap B$?

I am confused about the subset and intersection of these sets.

Comment: You need to know that a,b,c are distinct elements in order to make any conclusive statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ has two elements, $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b, c\}$. So an element is in $A$ if and only if it is $\{a,b\}$ or $\{b,c\}$. $\{b\}$ is neither of these, so $\{b\} \notin A$. Similarly, $b$ is neither of these, so $b \notin A$.

The intersection of $A$ and $B$ is the set of elements that are in both sets. $B$ has the elements $\{b\}$, $\{c\}$, and $\{a,b,c\}$, of which none are in $A$. So $A \cap B = \varnothing$, the empty set. Hence $\{b\} \in B$, but $\{b\} \notin A \cap B$.

Answer (score 0):

$\{b\} \notin A$ and $b \notin A$ by definition of $A$; only $\{a, b\} \in A$ and $\{b, c\} \in A$.

$A \cap B = \emptyset$, as there are no elements that are shared by $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is $\{b\} \in A$?

The set $A$ has two elements, which each happen to be sets themselves. Is $\{b\}$ one of them? Unwrap the outer set braces from the definition of $A$ and ask if $\{b\}$ matches one of $\{a,b\}$ or $\{b,c\}$.

> No, $\{b\} \neq \{a,b\}$ and $\{b\} \neq \{b,c\}$.

---

> Is $b \in A$?

Again, is $b$ one of the two elements listed in the definition of $A$?

> No. In this case, it's even easier to rule this out, as the elements of $A$ are themselves sets, so neither can be a lone element like $b$.

---

> Is $\{b\} \in A \cap B$?

> No. When we look at the intersection $A \cap B$, we're looking for elements that simultaneously appear in $A$ and $B$. A quick glance determines that there's no overlap at all: neither of the two elements of $A$ are the same as any of the three elements of $B$. In other words, $A \cap B = \varnothing$, so certainly $\{b\}$ is not contained in the intersection.